# Detect argument passing convention of a C library function

Tags: python, cpython

With pure Python functions you can pass arguments either by order (e.g. `foo(1, 2, 3)`) or by name (e.g. `foo(a=1, c=3, b=2)`).

Functions defined in C modules [can use either convention](http://starship.python.net/crew/mwh/toext/other-calling-conventions.html). You cannot say `range(stop=10, step=2)`, and so it is with most but not all functions implemented using C interface.

Is there a way to determine the argument passing convention of a function from within Python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears to be an [open bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue8350): there is simply no way to tell this.  Also, the issue is implementation-dependent: your code might work in (for example) PyPy, though I can't confirm this.

The devs on the bug page aren't sure whether to change the documentation style or the implementation, but I get the impression it's not a pressing issue for them either way.

Comment: In PyPy you can (functions and builtin functions are less different), but you might be surprised that for example range keyword arguments are named "x" "y" and "step" :) In general better not to do that